# Attaching parameters with javascript closures to default parameters in anonymous functions

Tags: javascript, closures, google-geocoder

I want to add some extra parameters to the Google geocoder API call as I'm running it in a loop, but am not sure how to append closure parameters to their anonymous function that already has default parameters that are passed in by the call to the API.

For example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
         // Geocoder stuff here
     });
}
```

I want to be able to use the value of i in the passed geocoder.geocode() anonymous function, but if I had a closure using `}(i));` on line 4 for example that would replace the first parameter which would break the geocoder.

Is there a way I can use closures, or pass the value of i into the anonymous function at all?

Effectively what I want to do is:

```
geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status, i) {
    alert(i); // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
}(i));
```

but working :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can access `i` directly from you anonymous function (via closure), but you need to capture it so that each call to `geocode` gets its own copy. As usual in javascript, adding another function will do the trick. I renamed the outer `i` variable to make it clearer:

```
for(var iter = 0; iter < 5; iter++) {
    (function(i) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
            // Geocoder stuff here
            // you can freely access i here
        });
    })(iter);
}
```

Comment: An even simpler solution! Should've posted sooner

Comment: I was going to say that it was confusing having `i` in the outer scope and inner scope, but I see you've fixed that now so I'll let you off :)

Comment: I suggest that this example is the best because others (they are simpler) don't work in my case: the i inside the geocoder callback function is always the last one in the loop. I guess, it depends on the asynchronous nature of the browser.

But this answer worked perfectly! +1!

Comment: I know this is old, but I want to correct the assumption @Igor made about scope and closures. It has nothing to do with the "asynchrous nature of the browser", but is rather due to the fact that each created anonymous function has a closure over the *exact same* scope; that means they are all referencing the same `i`, which is a single number. For further detail, please read [this chapter](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/scope%20&%20closures/ch5.md#loops--closure) of You Don't Know JS.

Comment: Worked for me! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 3):

```
function geoOuter(i) {
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
         // Geocoder stuff here
         // This has access to i in the outer function, which will be bound to
         // a different value of i for each iteration of the loop
     });
}

for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    geoOuter(i);
}
```

Oughta do it...

Comment: Such a simple answer. Thank you so much :-)